# how to exactly implement FACEBOOK plugin for PhoneGap android?

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am new to PhoneGap, i would like to know the exact procedure for facebook plugin for PhoneGap android.i just want to implement it and see.
i read few tutorials online...it asked me do download the FBandroid SDK from the facebook developers site..i did that and installed it in the following path

```
adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform-tools
```

with the command

```
adb install FBAndroid-2.0.apk
```

in the command prompt... i got a message successful but when i start my emulator...the emulator does not open and in my Log cat in eclipse...all commands RE RUNNING CONTINUOUSLY FOR 2-3 HOURS..

OR

when i start the same emulator once again..it opens up but i don't find that F symbol in my emulator home screen.

**please also Let me know what is the exact procedure before this and after this?**

please guide me....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete guide for the facebook plugin on android and iOS.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-facebook-plugin

Follow the steps to setup the plugin.

Comment: yeah manishkumar,i did follow that but..as i tried to exlain the situation...after installing FBANDROID sdk...the emulator does not open up..and the log cat is on... for 2-3 HOURS....

Comment: Do you mean the emulator did not boot up at all?

Comment: manishkumar,yes,it shows as the emulator is loading with the word ANDROID on the screen...some set of commands continuously go on....in the LogCat...
do you have a solution for this????

Comment: Well the android emulator can be really annoying at times. If you can grab yourself a device to test on then that will certainly help.